# Adding Page Numbers in Word

Tags: calibre, software, standard, synchronization, formatting

How do I add page numbers to an ebook in Microsoft Word, in the following format:

- No numbers on opening pages (Title page, Copyright, Dedication)
- First page Number appears at bottom of Chapter 1
- Second page (2) appears at top of next page in chapter
- Third page (3) appears at top of 3rd page in chapter and so on...
- Subsequent Chapters - First page in each Chapter lists page number at bottom (same as Chapter One)

I've been tinkering with this for about an hour, gone through Help pages in Word and can't figure it out. Is it really this hard? Perhaps opening file in Calibre and adding numbers there?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To do this, you will need to use Sections. Also, when you create a new section, make sure to disable the "Link to Previous" option so that the formatting starts where you want it to. Make sure your opening content is in one section, then start your first chapter in a second section. Add a footer to the first page of the chapter and insert your page number there. To get the rest of the page numbers to appear at the top, you will need to create a third section starting with the next page, then add a header with the page numbers in the header. When you start the second chapter, you will need a new section, and so on.

This behavior will vary depending on the version of Word you are using, so you may have to play with it some. This kind of formatting can be very frustrating with Word, and they certainly don't go out of their way to make it easy.

Answer (score 0):

Colby;

Here are some links for you to get started:
How to number chapters, appendixes, and pages in documents that contain both chapter and appendix headings in Word - http://support.microsoft.com/kb/290953

Overall this will give you the details that you've asked for to number your ebook the way you want to.

As to placement, you choose where in your Word document you put the page number. Normally this would be done in the header or the footer. However it does not have to be put in this location.

Number pages differently in different sections - https://support.office.com/en-in/article/Number-pages-differently-in-different-sections-1ba9047e-4534-460f-8003-12a81bb527f3

Will help you setting up the document the way you've stated in your original question.

Hope that this helps you out. It looks more daunting than it is. Work through these two pages and you'll get the idea of how to get this done.

Regards
Andrew Martin